# Compact operator with closed image

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact operator between two normed spaces. If $K(X)$ is closed, does this necessarily imply that $K(B)$ is closed?

where $B$ is the closed unit ball?

Comment: Take the linear functional $x=(1/2,1/4,1/8,\ldots)\in\ell_1$ on $X=c_0$. Its range is all of $\Bbb R$, but the image of $B(c_0)$ under $x$ is $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider $f:c_0\rightarrow R$ defined by $f(e_i)={1\over 2^i}$, it is compact and the image of the unit ball is $(-2,2)$. where $c_0$ is the set of sequences with finitely non zero terms endowed with $\|\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: So $(-2,2)$ is closed but not compact, right?

Comment: it is neither closed nor compact.

Comment: All right! But know if in addition I assume K to be an open operator... then it would hold right?

Comment: yes, it is also open

Comment: But in your example, is $f(e_i)$ closed?

Comment: a singleton in $R$ is closed.

Comment: @TsemoAristide $(-2,2)$ is an open interval in $\mathbb R$ which most certainly is not closed...

Comment: I'm a bit confused... it seams so that @Math1000 and Tsemo Aristide you both give opposite answer. Isn't it?

Comment: Ah - I misread the question. My apologies.

Comment: How is $f$ defined on all of $l^\infty?$ As an infinite sum?

Comment: You might change it to $c_0$ or the space of sequence $(x_1, \cdots, x_n, \cdots)$ which vanishes for large $n$.

Comment: So now $f(c_0)$ is closed, right?

Comment: @MorganeMaPh $f(c_0) = \mathbb R$. (This is true for any nonzero functional)